# Subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}_{\text{bounded}}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}_{\text{bounded}}$ is defined as sequence $f$ bounded by a number $M \in \mathbb R$ such that $|f| \le M$.

Since $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a vector space, if $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}_{\text{bounded}}$ includes $\{0\}$  will it be automatically a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: From the context, I guess $N$ is supposed to be the set of natural numbers, rather than some constant integer, right? In that case, I would suggest to make it clear by using $\mathbb N$ (typed as `\mathbb N`) instead. In addition, it looks nicer if the subscript is written as `\text{bounded}`.

Comment: yes, sorry I am new to this. Thank you for the help

Comment: No problem. Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also prove that if $f,g\in R_{bounded}^N$ and $r,s\in R$, then $rf+sg\in R_{bounded}^N$. Namely, that $R_{bounded}^N$ is closed by linear combinations.

This will follow from the triangle inequality $$|rf+sg|\leq |s||f|+|r||g|$$
and the boundedness of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: OscarRascal, I haven't gone through this unit yet at the uni, but I've read some articles on Hamel basis,fact that every infinite-dimensional space has open subspaces and linear mapping I learned a bit in advance. Is that useful here?